# How will i set default radio button checked and know which radio button is checked from the radio-group in a reactive-form?

Tags: angular, radio-button, radio-group, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a group of radio-buttons. I want to set a default radio button 'checked' and whenever dynamically the other radio buttons are clicked how can i capture which radio button.so,that i can use accordingly in my conditional statements in my typescript."CHECKED" Tag will not work

```
<form [formGroup]="Form">
  <div class="bx--row">
    <fieldset class="bx--fieldset">
      <legend class="bx--label">HEYHELLOWORLD</legend>
      <div class="bx--form-item">
        <div class="bx--radio-button-group ">
          <input id="radio-button-1" class="bx--radio-button" type="radio" formControlName="selectedOption"
            value="0" checked>
          <label for="radio-button-1" class="bx--radio-button__label">
            <span class="bx--radio-button__appearance"></span>
            HEY<br>
          </label>
          <input id="radio-button-2" class="bx--radio-button" type="radio" formControlName="selectedOption"
            value="1" tabindex="0">
          <label for="radio-button-2" class="bx--radio-button__label">
            <span class="bx--radio-button__appearance"></span>
            HELLO<br>
          </label>
          <input id="radio-button-3" class="bx--radio-button" type="radio" formControlName="selectedOption"
            value="2" tabindex="0">
          <label for="radio-button-3" class="bx--radio-button__label">
            <span class="bx--radio-button__appearance"></span>
            WORLD
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

Above is my HTML part with reactive form
TS:

```
    heyForm() {
      this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
          selectedOption: ["", Validators.required],
      });
    }
```

How will i get the value selected in TS file so that i can use which radio button is clicked in my conditional statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initilize the form control with the value of  whatever radio button you want to be checked as default. There is no need of adding a default `checked` attribute in the any of the radio buttons

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
    selectedOption: ["1", Validators.required], // this will make the second radio button checked as default.
});
```

If you want to access which radio button was clicked, you can do it through:

```
this.form.get('selectedOption').value
```

Have a function fetching the above value on `(change)` event over the radio buttons.

For example:

```
<input (change)="foo()" id="radio-button-1" class="bx--radio-button" type="radio" formControlName="selectedOption" value="0">
// inside the method foo() check for the currently selected radio button
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kw8bhf